# Konica Minolta multifunction printers default to double sided printing

Tags: windows, printing, drivers, windows-10, network-printer

We have 50 machines that use 3 different models of Konica Minolta printers:

- bizhub C3850FS
- bizhub C258
- bizhub C280

I've been installing the latest driver and it has been brought to my attention that these printers are defaulting to printing on both sides.

Every time I change the printer settings they seem to reset. Either that or the defaults I'm setting are not changing.

Is there a way to manage all these printers and control drivers and settings from a central location?

Comment: How are you going about changing the printer settings? How are the printer queues added to the workstations; manually, via GP, something else?

Comment: On the printer itselft, any setting for that? as if I remember correctly the konica with bidirectional setup in the port status the print driver monitor will read the printer configuration to update itselft. (thus surelly why it flush your config)